# How is this equation supposed to simplify?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

To start with I am taking the derivative of $f(x) = 6x^{4/3} - 3x^{1/3}$ which should be fairly simple.

I get:

$$ f'(x) = 8x^{1/3} - x^{-2/3}$$

which is clearly the same as:

$$ 8x^{1/3} - \frac {1}{x^{2/3}} $$

However, this is supposed to simplify to

$$ \frac {8x-1}{x^{2/3}} $$

and i don't really understand how. Can someone please explain? Thanks :)

Comment: $a-{1\over b}={ab-1\over b}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably talking about 
$$f(x) = 6x^{\frac43} - 3x^{\frac13}$$

Your calculations so far are correct. Now make sure you get the same denominator. Expand the first fraction with $$x^{\frac23}$$.
This results in

$$\frac{8x^{\frac13}\cdot x^{\frac23}}{x^{\frac23}}-\frac{1}{x^{\frac23}} = \frac{8x}{x^{\frac23}}-\frac{1}{x^{\frac23}} = \frac{8x-1}{x^{\frac23}}$$

Alright?

Comment: That makes perfect sense and I'm not sure how I couldn't figure that out myself. Thank you!

Comment: No worries :). Next time for sure!